# Error 413 when using curl to post

Tags: php, post, curl, get

I get error 413 every time i try to post data with php script using curl.
I can "get" web pages,but when i use "post" the script dies with

```
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided
 in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
```

I have a py script,which works.
Here is an example code that doesn't work:

```
 $q=curl_init(POSTURL);

 curl_setopt($q,CURLOPT_POST,true);
 curl_setopt($q,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);


 $post=array("q"=>2);
   $ss=curl_setopt($q,CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost");
        curl_setopt($q,CURL_POSTFIELDS,$post);
 $f=curl_exec($q);
 curl_close($q);
        echo $f." is error";
```

I don't know if the problem is with apache,with my script or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Has the webserver been configured to allow POSTs? On Apache that would be most likely be a `<Limit>` directive. Or has the `LimitRequestBody` been set to 0 (or at least a value smaller than your post is turning out to be)?

Comment: no.The script doesn't work even when it's not on the server(for example in /usr/)

Comment: Doesn't matter where your curl script is, I mean the script that's being POSTed to. You're getting a server-side error response, which means the problem is with the web server and/or the script you're trying to talk to.

Comment: But that happens with every url address,not only with those on my server.The example doesn't work for "example.com" and the python script works.

Comment: Then something's goofy with your PHP and/or curl configuration.